# Is there any Windows text editor that allows to open links in text in browser incognito mode?

Tags: windows, gratis, text-editor

Is there any free text editor on Windows that allows (or has a plug-in that allows) to configure what happens when url's in the text are clicked on (e.g. to pass command line to the browser so that the page opens up in browser incognito mode), similar to how Zim Desktop Wiki allows to configure programs associated with certain type of embedded documents or links (described at http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Help/Default_Applications.html). E.g. Notepad++ has a way to configure whether links open up in default browser or not, but not the choice of browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor has new plugin, which gives commands to open URL (under caret) in main browsers in incognito/private mode:

- Chrome
- Chrome, private (incognito) mode
- Firefox
- Firefox, private mode
- Opera
- Opera, private mode
- IE
- IE, private mode
- custom tool program

It supports click on URLs too.
You can configure paths to browsers, using menu "Options / Settings-plugins / Open URL".

Comment: hmm, I got it to work, but is there a way to specify which one of the browsers to run by default, without having to click every time on the dropdown and pick the browser?

Comment: handle_click=1 looked promising, but setting it to 0 just stopped menu from popping up...

Comment: @ZimUser To auto open any item from browsers menu, now added option "action_on_click", see readme/readme.txt

Comment: awesome, updated the plugin with your change, it's now doing what I had hoped for, thanks a lot for the quick turnaround!